# Set root JSON object value to array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Suppose I have this function

```
function(json) { ... }
```

in which the json has the following structure

```
{
    "Prop1":"some value",
    "Array1":[ { "Value":"1" }, { "Value":"2" } ]
}
```

is it somehow possible to modify this 'json' parameter to look like below, even outside of this function?

```
{
    [ { "Value":"1" }, { "Value":"2" } ]
}
```

In other words, I want that array1 to become the value of the root of this json parameter.

I cannot simply do

```
 json = json.array; // nor can I do
 json.push(something); // since the parameter is an object, not an array
```

since the parameter is passed by reference and I actually have to modify its contents if I want the changes to be visible on the outside.

Any tips are much appreciated!

P.S: In this scenario, nor is returning the appropriate value okay, since this function is an event handler for some library and the only way I can influence it is by modifying this parameter.

**Later edit (2018-11-14):**
My mistake regarding the JSON format. The format should simply be

```
[ { "Value":"1" }, { "Value":"2" } ]
```

without the opening and closing brackets.

Comment: an object needs a key.

Comment: what is wrong with "json = json.Array1;"

Comment: @bhspencer that simply changes the local name to point to a new array, it doesn't change the referenced object, which is what the OP seems to want. Outside the function the changes won't have any effect.

Comment: oh ok. That sounds like an unpleasant side effect.

Answer (score 1):

This is not valid JSON

```
{
    [ { "Value":"1" }, { "Value":"2" } ]
}
```

as Nina pointed out, it's in object notation, and objects require a key.

But *a plain array is* valid JSON

```
[ { "Value":"1" }, { "Value":"2" } ]
```

and is also the root of the JSON string, as you implied needing. I assume this is because the library you are using is ingesting only the parameters contained within `Array1` and you can't provide a key.

So, simply `JSON.parse(eventstring).Array1`.

Is that what you're looking for?

Incidentally, most "naked" primary data types are also valid JSON, such that these are also parseable:

```js
console.dir(JSON.parse(true))
console.dir(JSON.parse(null))
console.dir(JSON.parse(1))
console.dir(JSON.parse("1"))
```

Comment: Thanks both you and Nina for the key observation. I've corrected this aspect in the question.
Problem is, how do I assign the result of either `json.Array1` or `JSON.parse(eventstring).Array1` to my json parameter? As stated in the question, I can't do `json = somethingElse;` since this won't take effect on the instance the caller sent. I have to actually modify the reference I am given through that parameter.

Comment: @CiprianVilcan I'm not sure I follow. It sounds like the question is "I need to change this thing, but I can't change it, how do I do it?" I'm missing something in the way your library is interacting with your code - can you post actual code?

Comment: Btw, string is not a valid JSON. In your example it is converted to an integer.